# .htaccess while upgrading web app

Tags: apache, deployment, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am writing one web application using PHP/CodeIginter.

Now, I want to add a .htaccess while I am upgrading the application in the server.
The purpose of this .htaccess will be: -

1. It'll allow normal operation if the user is accessing

   - from some specific IPs, and
   - Using a particular host name alias
   - has a query string parameter "upgrading=1" in the URL
2. Otherwise, it'll show a message: "site is under construction".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=127.0.0.0 [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=specific.host.example [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^([^&]*&)*upgrading=1(&.*)?$
RewriteRule !^maintenance\.html$ maintenance.html [L]
```